# how to create a like button, which a user can only like once in django website?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, django-models

i want to create a fully functional like button, when can be like only once by a user .

i have already create a like button but that is not i am looking for, my current like button can be liked as many times as user want to like .

```
enter code here
##models.py

class Images(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
              related_name='images_created', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True,         
               blank=True)
    message_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = InheritanceManager()

##views.py

def like_treasure(request):
    treasure_id = request.POST.get('treasure_id', None)
    message_likes = 0
    if (treasure_id):
        treasure = Postsms.objects.get(id=int(treasure_id))
        if treasure is not None:
            message_likes = treasure.message_likes + 1
            treasure.message_likes = message_likes
            treasure.save()
    return HttpResponse(message_likes)


## $
$('button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
    url : '/like_treasure/',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { treasure_id : element.attr("data-id")},
    success : function(response){
        element.html(' ' + response);
 }

});

});

##html

 <button style="background-color: red" id ="likes" data-id="{{foo.id}}"
   class="btn btn-mini  glyphicon glyphicon-heart"
   type="button" >
   {% if foo.message_likes > 0 %} {{ foo.message_likes }} {% endif %}
```

Comment: This is crying for an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You could use `django-secretballot`

Answer (score 0):

Take a Boolean field instead of IntegerField in images model. So, a user can like image only once. Rest, handle it on front end with boolean field.

Comment: how can i handle it on front end

Comment: {% if not foo.like %} <button style="background-color: red" id ="likes" data-id="{{foo.id}}"
   class="btn btn-mini  glyphicon glyphicon-heart"
   type="button" disabled> {% endif %}

Comment: Disable button if image like boolean check is True.

Comment: wrong answer , because i want to store all user likes in database , Boolean is only true or false , i want to count all likes , ..

Comment: You will have separate objects for every image. Try ManytoManyField to User in Image model.

Comment: also tried , getting error cannot add manytomanyfield to int , plz check my views.py you will understand  .

Comment: message_likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)

Comment: and what view i make for this .